# The constructor intent is undefined

Tags: android, android-intent, motionevent

I am trying to pass "message" string to MainActivity using intent, I tried everything but still no luck. Can you help me through this.

```
public class MoveMouse {

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch(eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // new position
            final float x = event.getX();
            final float y = event.getY();

            //  get delta
            final float deltax = x - this.lastX;
            final float deltay = y - this.lastY;
            // set last position
            this.lastX = x;
            this.lastY = y;

            String message = (deltax + "," + deltay);
            //intent
            Intent ins = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            ins.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ins.putExtra("mv", message);
            this.startActivity(ins);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MouseMove` class is not a `Context` such as an `Activity` so using `this` where a `Context` is required won't work.

There isn't enough context (sic) in the question to tell how you should be passing the `Context`, but consider passing one as an argument when instantiating your `MouseMove`.

Comment: I don't get it, how can I define `Context`?

Comment: And how can I pass an argument??

Comment: Depends really where `MouseMove` class is and how you instantiate it.

Comment: `MouseMove` class and `MainActivity` class are different java file.